# Console line output redirecting blocks file and prevents to read it

Tags: php, console, output

How to redirect output from console app (php.exe in this case) to a text file (output.txt in this case) without blocking it? Php script takes a lot of time and I need to async read output from it (from httpd->javascript->webpage)

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind - passthru php function helped me a lot :)